# Detectar click y doble click en HTML

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer para detectar si se ha hecho un click simple o un doble click sobre un elemento HTML `<div>` he probado el siguiente código:

```
<div onclick="alert('un click')" ondblclick="alert('doble click')"> Click aqui</div>
```

El problema es que no me detecta el doble click, siempre me muestra el mensaje "un click", como hago para detectar uno u otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible utilizar ambos eventos a la vez. Puedes hacer alguna especie de truco como el siguiente:

```js
var DELAY = 700,
    clicks = 0,
    timer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a")
    .bind("click", function(e){

        clicks++;  //count clicks

        if(clicks === 1) {

            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                alert('Single Click'); //perform single-click action

                clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter

            }, DELAY);

        } else {

            clearTimeout(timer);  //prevent single-click action

            alert('Double Click');  //perform double-click action

            clicks = 0;  //after action performed, reset counter
        }

    })
    .bind("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
```

Aunque no entiendo para que quieres hacer algo así.

Comment: Lo que deseo hacer es que al hacer clic hago una acción, si se hace un doble clic ejecuto otra acción, usando el mismo elemento, ¿Conoces alguna otra forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Tiene que ser sobre el mismo elemento?, puedes crear dos elementos haciendo funciones distintas. No se que quieres hacer, pero me parece que una funcionalidad así puede ser poco intuitiva para un usuario, por algo estos eventos por defecto no funcionan a la vez

Answer (score 3):

Lo haces de la forma correcta, **ondblclick** sirve para realizar un evento de doble click sobre un elemento, sin embargo en el ejemplo que muestras el resultado siempre sera el **alert("un click")**, ya que al intentar hacer doble click, **onclick** detecta la primera interacción que haces al dar click sobre el elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de la forma en la que cada vez que se realice un dobleclick sobre determinado elemento, lo detectes con el evento addEventListener. Puedes implementar lo mismo para el click ejemplo tomado de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_dblclick.asp).

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").dblclick(function(){
            alert("Se ha hecho doble click sobre el Div.");
        });
    });
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    </head>
    <body>

<div>Haz doble click.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que hagas un click o doble click te tomará el primer click, ocupas hacer algo extra, como por ejemplo medir el tiempo desde que diste el primer click si tarda por ejempl 2 segundos y no hay otro click realizar la acción.

puedes usar el **`setTimeout`**

```js
var dobleClick = false;
function onclick() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (dobleClick == false) {
      //Hacer algo
    }
    else {dobleClick = false;}
},500);
}
```